# How to view the arguments in events under truffle console?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle

Hello awesome ethereum community, Need help in viewing the arguments under event. I am using event AnyException for error handling. I pass a string argument to my event in my solidity file. When I run the function, I would like to view the string argument passed to my event. Currently, I just see `args: [Object]` . How do I vew the argument in truffle console?

**EventTest.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;
  contract EventTest {
    event AnyException(string message);

    function testEvent(string s) public returns (bool) {
      if (keccak256(s) == keccak256("titu")) {
        AnyException("Invalid input: titu");
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
  }
```

**Truffle console**

```
truffle(development)> var et; EventTest.deployed().then(function(deployed){et=deployed;});
undefined
truffle(development)> et.testEvent("titu");
{ tx: '0xcc99eeacdf9cf83aa82e4a1284a35eac71abfad85d91564fbbb4f611b7f52d69',
  receipt: 
   { transactionHash: '0xcc99eeacdf9cf83aa82e4a1284a35eac71abfad85d91564fbbb4f611b7f52d69',
     transactionIndex: 0,
     blockHash: '0x81f8c761825b96985e222e713fa7e17f1cabee1a130ca7651e0f8e0f1ba72a12',
     blockNumber: 13,
     gasUsed: 24374,
     cumulativeGasUsed: 24374,
     contractAddress: null,
     logs: [ [Object] ] },
  logs: 
   [ { logIndex: 0,
       transactionIndex: 0,
       transactionHash: '0xcc99eeacdf9cf83aa82e4a1284a35eac71abfad85d91564fbbb4f611b7f52d69',
       blockHash: '0x81f8c761825b96985e222e713fa7e17f1cabee1a130ca7651e0f8e0f1ba72a12',
       blockNumber: 13,
       address: '0x1940ce494ecf457feefa4d6874542353db01bf9f',
       type: 'mined',
       event: 'AnyException',
       args: [Object] } ] }
```

Comment: `logs` is an array, so you can inspect `logs[0]`, `logs[1]`. In this case, just `logs[0]`. `args` is an object. You can inspect it with something like `logs[0].args`. You hope to see named arguments, so you could `logs[0].args.oneProperty`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you, @Rob Hitchens for the tip. Here is the solution by printing the json argument returned on the console.

```
truffle(development)> var et; EventTest.deployed().then(function(deployed){et=deployed;});
undefined
truffle(development)> et.testEvent("titu").then(function(ret){console.log(ret.logs[0].args.message);});
Invalid input: titu
```